# Display Landscape version of the layout by default

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, landscape

Is it possible to force AS to show layout preview in landscape version by default? Quick Google search & Setting search didn't help

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking about how to code your app so it will default to landscape? Or how to make your phone show an app as landscape, unrelated to programming?

Comment: Please don't tag with Android when you're in fact referring to Android Studio. When you're asking about the preview in Android Studio, that's an Android Studio problem - not an Android problem.

Answer (score -1):

Not quite a setting, but if you choose to create a specific landscape version in the `res/layout-land` folder Android Studio will display these variants in landscape orientation by default in the Design/Preview screen.

An easy way to create a landscape variant for an existing layout file is by clicking the rotating phone icon you can also use to switch the preview orientation and then select "Generate landscape variant".

Answer (score -1):

if you want your application to be in landscape mode by default just add this code below in your AndroidManifest file and modify your activity layout design to landscape mode

```
<activity android:name=".MainClass"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
```

if you want your application will allow portrait and landscape mode also just modify the **screenOrientation** into  `android:screenOrientation="sensor"` and adjust you activity layout design to portrait and landscape mode